# Find the strongest point of the magnetic field from three long conducting wires

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, maxwell-equations

Consider three long power lines buried in the ocean, with (from left to right) current $\frac{I}{2}, I, \frac{I}{2}$, where the direction of the current in the edge cables are negative $z$ (in to the image) and the middle one positive $z$ (out of the image).

[image]

I know that the magnetic field from a long current is given by Ampere-Maxwells laws as,
$$B(r_c)=\frac{I\mu_0}{2\pi r_c}\hat{\theta}.$$

Apparently, it is "easy" to see that the combined magnetic field from the three cables at the ocean floor is strongest directly above the middle cable. However, I do not see this at all. How can I convince myself that this is the case?

Comment: Why don't you draw in some field lines? There you can quickly see some more and less interesting regions.

Answer (score 0):

The red spot as answer seems wrong.

Magnetic field of a single current-carrying wire is strongest on surface of the wire. When two other wires are much farther from it than is the  thickness if the middle wire $2r$, their contribution seems almost negligible near the middle wire (compare $I/2a$ to $I/r$). So the proper approximate answer would be "somewhere on the first wire surface".

Then, we can see that magnetic field is not of the same strength on the whole surface of the middle wire, since it is influenced by the two other wires. When you draw directions and magnitudes of those contributions, it turns out those contributions cancel on top and bottom point of the middle wire surface. Also, they do not cancel on other  points, and they enhance the middle wire magnetic field on that part of the surface which lies on the line connecting the three wires, on both sides. So there is no single point with strongest field, there are two - one facing the leftmost wire, and one facing the rightmost wire.

Comment: " at the ocean floor is strongest directly above the middle cable." ocean floor being the line

Comment: @jgklsdjfgkldsfaSDF I don't see your point.